# Alternative algorithm whose runtime is better than this algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I want an algorithm with run time O(n). The problem is, to know if an array of integers contains the same number 3 times.

I tried this, but the runtime is O(n^3). This code is in Java.

```java
public boolean ThreeEqualElements(int[] arr )
{
    int n = arr.length;
    for(int i =0 ; i <=n-1 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j <= i-1 ; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0 ; k <= j-1 ; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]==arr[j]&& arr[j]==arr[k])
                    return true ;
            }
        }
    }
    return  false ;
}
```

Comment: Count the frequency of numbers, and end as soon as you find the third occurrence of a number.

Comment: O(n) doesn't seam feasible because you must scroll the table and store the count for each number in some kind of dictionary where search and insertion can't be linear.

Comment: @Graffito with  using  hash-map  it will be O(n) but i don't know the hashmap yet so i did it on O(nlog(n)) this is the code :  public static boolean countFreqSorted(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        for(int i = 0 ; i <= n-1 ; i++)
        {
            int count =1 ;
            while (i<n-1 && arr[i]==arr[i+1])
            {
                count++;
                i++;
                if(count == 3)
                    return true ;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash table to store the count of each element in the array to solve the problem with runtime O(n). Iterate through the array once, increasing the count of each element in the hash table. Then, iterate through the hash table, looking for any counts that equal 3. Return true if you find an element with count 3. Return false if you iterate through the entire hash table and don't find any elements with count 3.

```
public boolean ThreeEqualElements(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        count.put(arr[i], count.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0) + 1);
        if (count.get(arr[i]) == 3) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This solution has a bias : it lets non O(n) operations to the use of the Hash table. As a whole (your code and the HashMap library), the process is not O(n).